# (iphone) how to show that imageview is tapped as uibutton?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uibutton

With UIButton, you can see that a user clicked the button (image turns into gray).

I'd like that behavior in UIImageView and wonder how it can be done.
Another possible approach is to use UIButton, let it react visually(turns into gray)
But pretend touch didn't occur.(because I need to pass the touch event to the superview or nextresponder).

Thank you.

- Edit

I actually ended up subclassing UIButton and
implement touchesBegan/moved/ended

```
- (void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
{   
    [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
}
```

first touchesBegan for highlightning,
second one for the proper handling I need.

Wonder calling two touchesBegan would be fine..

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer to your question.

Put an UIImageView on your view through Interface Builder and make it an IBOutlet in .h and name it "img". and write this code in the .m

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

UITouch *touch  = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
if (CGRectContainsPoint([img frame], [touch locationInView:self.view])) {

    img.alpha = 0.5;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"frame" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    img.alpha = 1.0;

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    NSLog(@"Image Touched");

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a property, named **highlightedImage**, in UIImageView. By setting this property, UIImageView will change to this image when touched.

Comment: ah i saw that, definitely would be great if I don't have to provide another image for highlighted state.

Comment: if i have to go this route, how should I create the highlightedimage? (as appeared in button selected) change alpha?

Comment: Generally, I will add a CATransition animation effect to produce fade out animation.

Answer (score 0):

Your second options sounds best. Simply use UIButton and set either the image or the background image. If you subclass UIButton (which is in its turn a subclass of UIView) you can catch all touch events and pass them on to underlying views like so:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // returning nil will ignore touches on this view
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: would it still visually change the image though?